# Dropdown menu inside a table - then update

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table populated from a mysql database. One of the fields is "status". I would like this cell to be a drop down box inside the table, so I can then update the particular field.

This code, correctly displays the table and currently it displays the "status" filed inside a text box that I can edit successfully. I would like this to be a drop down though.

```
<?php

require_once('db_connect.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM queries
WHERE SR = '$_GET[SR]'
")
or die(mysql_error());


echo '<form name="Form" action="update.php" method="post">';
echo 
"<table id='box-table-b'>
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>SR</th>
 <th>Product</th>
 <th>Status</th>
 </tr>

  </thead>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<tbody>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['SR'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="status" value="'.$row['status'].'" />' . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</tbody>";
   }
 echo "</table>";
 echo '<input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" />';
 echo '</form>';


?>
```

Can someone please show me how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you should use the `<select></select>` tags. Example:

```
<select>
<option>Item 1</option>
<option>Item 2</option>
<option> ... </option>
<option selected="selected">Item N</option>
</select>
```

In this specific example, the dropdown would appear with "Item N" selected by default.

As a side note, isn't using mysql_* functions bad practice in general?

Answer (score 0):

by drop down menu I guess you mean a `select` tag, anything more complicated that this requires a custom implementation.

This requires 2 steps: first you need to create the select tag and populate it with option tags, then you need to set the desired value as selected.

to create the select tag:

```
$myselect="<select id='status' name='status'>";
foreach($status_values as $e){
     $myselect.="<option value='$e'>$e</option>";
}
$myselect.="</select>";
```

`$status_value` is a array, you can have in your code or get it from a query.

To select the correct one you can add the following if to the code above:

```
$myselect="<select id='status' name='status'>";
foreach($status_values as $e){
     if($e == $row['status']){
          $myselect.="<option value='$e' SELECTED>$e</option>";
     }else
          $myselect.="<option value='$e'>$e</option>";
     }
}
$myselect.="</select>";
```